# Stack Level Too Deep, Maybe recursive but not sure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback, stack-level

I'm getting a `Stack Level too deep` error and I think it's to do with the following code but i'm not sure how to fix it:

```
   after_save :update_milestone

   def update_milestone
      if order % 50 == 0
         self.update_attributes(is_milestone: true)
      else
         self.update_attributes(is_milestone: false)
      end
   end
```

Any thoughts

Comment: Rather than using that if statement with two updates ... why not use the value of the conditional in your update? Like this: `self.update_attributes(is_milestone: order % 50 == 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling update_attributes which hits validations. This then triggers the callback after_save which is causing the errors.

You want:

```
self.update_column(:is_milestone, value)
```

This won't trigger validations.

Comment: `after_save` -> `update_milestone` -> `self.update_attributes` -> `after_save` -> `update_milestone` -> `self.update_attributes` -> ...